# how to preallocate a matrix in Matlab for a 'while' loop?

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop, out-of-memory, pre-allocation

I want to preallocate a matrix in matlab to get rid of out of memory error, but how can i use preallocating for a while loop?
we use preallocating for a for loop like this:

```
m=10000;
x=zeros(m,1)

for i = 1:m
    x(i) = i
end
```

but what if i want to do this for a while loop

```
m = 10000
x = 1
i=0
some_criteria = 10
while x<some_criteria
     i = i+1
     x(i) = i
     some_criteria = f(x)
end
```

Comment: Not preallocating is not as bad as it used to be, but it is still good practice to do so. One method is to create an array that is large enough for any run, then crop the array after the loop to the right size.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 m = 10000
x=zeros([],1);
i=0
some_criteria = 10
while x<some_criteria
     i = i+1
     x(i,1) = i
     some_criteria = f(x)
end
```

if you write x(i) instead of x(i,1), the result will be a row vector.

Comment: sorry, i've used a bad example here, cause in my problem the criteria for while loop is convergence. that is if gradient absolute is smaller than a thereshold then stop. so we don't know the exact iteration.

Comment: OP asks how to preallocate, you are not preallocating here. The array grows with every loop iteration. This is not as expensive as it used to be, but it still is more expensive than preallocating.